# Connect to Oracle DB from Excel (VBA)

Tags: vba, oracle, excel, oledb

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle DB from VBA but i don't know which Driver use (to download and install) and also i don't know which reference add.

The error i'm getting is that driver is unknown (inside my connection string I've used ORAOLEDB, OLEDB etc)

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: OLEDB provider: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/utilsoft-087491.html the only ref you would need would be for ActiveX Data Objects.

Comment: Most likely your Excel is 32-bit. In this case you have to install also the 32-bit version of Oracle Provider for OLE DB - the "bitness" of Excel and Oracle has to be the same.